# Assassin Game Python Error

Tags: python, list, indexing, chain

We were given this assignment:

"The game of Assassin is a simple game played on university campuses where each player is assigned a target to assassinate by simply saying “you’re dead” to them.  Of course with thousands of people on campus and only a few dozen in the game you never know who is looking to assassinate you.  Once you assassinate someone you take on the target they were looking for.  If this happens to be you then you are the winner.  To ensure that this works properly the targets must form a continuous “chain.” Write a program that allows the user to enter their target assignments and output whether it is valid or not. based on if there is a continuous “chain.”  Each person in the list is represented by position in the list.  The value at the position is their target.  E.g.
0   1   2   3   4   5   6
4   3   0   5   6   2   1   Valid"

Here is my code:

```
people=[]
steps=[]
valid=True

while True:
    person=int(input("Enter the target(-1 to exit):"))
    if person==-1: break
    people.append(person)

for i in range(len(people)):
    if len(people[0])!=0:
        valid=False
        break
    elif len(people[0])==0: break
    steps.append(people[0])

for i in range(len(jumps)):
    if jumps[i-1]==jumps[i]:
        valid=False
if valid==False:                 #program MUST check if the flag is false before checking for length
    print('invalid')             #of the jumps list compared to the victims list.
elif len(jumps)==len(victims):
    print('valid')
elif len(jumps)!=len(victims):
    print('invalid')
```

Currently, I get this error:

```
File "C:/Users/Wisdom1/Desktop/ListAssign6.py", line 14, in 
<module>
if len(people[0])!=0:
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I do not know why this is but if someone could explain the occurrence of this error statement to me, that would be greatly appreciated.  Also, if there are any other errors that are in this code please let me know.  The output that I would like to achieve would be that any sequence input-ed other than 4305621, the program will output that it is invalid.  Thanks.

Comment: Don't ask someone else to do your homework. The entire point is for you to figure it out

Comment: I am not asking someone to create a code for me.  That would be asking someone to do my homework.  I have done some work here to the best of my ability and asking someone to revise it a bit for me.  You have the two of them confused.

Comment: Ok... but please try googling around for help as well. There are tons of questions like this already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`people` is a list.  `people[0]` however is an integer.  And, as your error says, you can't use `len` with integers since they are non-iterable.

If you want to see if the length of `people` is not `0`, remove `[0]`:

```
if len(people)!=0:
```

Or, if you want to see if `people[0]` does not equal `0`, remove `len`:

```
if people[0]!=0:
```